# Can I have a column named "status" in FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

I have the following code:

app/models/thing.rb

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :thing_id, :status
end
```

spec/factories/things.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  sequence :thing_id do |n|
    n
  end

  factory :thing do
    thing_id {generate :thing_id}
    status "Success"
  end
end
```

spec/controllers/my_controller/spec.rb

```
describe MyController do
  describe 'GET /index' do
    it 'must have a status' do
      FactoryGirl.create(:thing, status: 'Success')
      get :index
      expect(response).to be_success
      # there's more here but it's not relevant to this question
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:thing, status: 'Success')
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `status=' for #<Thing:0x0000323493ce28>
```

This appears to be because "status" is a reserved word in either ActiveRecord or FactoryGirl. Is there a way to get a column named "status"?

Comment: Are you sure the `Thing` model has an attribute `status`?

Comment: Yep. I've edited my question to include the code for thing.rb.

Comment: I think to @JiříPospíšil's point - are you sure that you actually have an attribute named `status` in your schema?  `attr_accessible` is not the same as `attr_accessor`.

Comment: Oh wow, I feel dumb. Went back and checked the migration and it isn't there. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I missed that column in my migration, so it didn't exist on the model.

Be sure to check your migrations!

Comment: Thanks about improve my english syntax.